# RubyMine does not version two of my project folders

Tags: vagrant, rubymine, cookbook

So I have a project that also uses `Vagrant`, which installs cookbooks into my project.
Under the `cookbooks` folder I have various cookbooks like one for PostgreSQL and etc..

Now I am versioning that `cookbook` folder also to my repository. But there is a problem with two cookbooks that do not want to be versioned for some reason.

[image]

I think the problem might be because these two folders are downloaded from a github repo?
Anyways, when I try to add them under the Default changelist, nothing happens, RubyMine says nothing but also does not put them under that changelist so I could push them into my repo.

How might I overcome this problem?

EDIT: I had to remove the .git files from the cookbooks. After that I was able to VC them.

Comment: Where did you put the git repository on? `vboxsf`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing the .gitingore files from the folders that caused the problem.